# How to handle multiple json fields in gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse a json to an object which gives me details of every entity attached to a bank.

My json looks like :

```
{
    "href" : "abc", 
    "configurations" : 
    [
        {
           "type" : "bank-customer",
           "properties" : {
                "cust-name" : "foo",
                "acc-no" : "12345"
            }
        }, 
        {
           "type" : "bank-employee",
           "properties" : {
                "empl-name" : "foo",
                "empl-no" : "12345"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The properties for various entity "type" is different.

Creating a pojo for this is the challenge. My properties.java will have to include all properties irrespective of the type of the property :

```
public class Configurations {
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String entityType;
    @SerializedName("properties")
    @Expose
    private Properties properties;
}

public class Properties {
    @SerializedName("cust-name")
    @Expose
    private String custName;
    @SerializedName("empl-no")
    @Expose
    private String emplNo;
    @SerializedName("empl-name")
    @Expose
    private String emplName;
    @SerializedName("acc-no")
    @Expose
    private String accNo;
}
```

This is painful when I have a lot of entity types and property per entity type. Is there any other way I can parse this json into different property objects for different entity types? I am using gson to parse the JSON

Note : I can't make any changes to the json itself.

Comment: You could swap your Properties class against a Map<String, Object> - then you will be able to parse all kinds of "entity types" - but you still need to handle the different types somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with mauros answer.

But you can also create a interface hierarchy and implement [Instance Creator](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator).

Answer (score 0):

Its can be easily solved by using `alternate` keyword from [@SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

```
public class Properties {

    @SerializedName(value="cust-name", alternate={"empl-name", "user-name"})
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("acc-no", alternate={"empl-no", "user-id"})
    @Expose
    private String id;

    //setter and getters
}
```